# How to display INFINITELY nested comments from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

so each comment is its own document. is this how i nest comments in each other, when a user replies to one?
and if something is nested lets say as much as 10 deep in replies, how do I do a for loop to loop through it all?

```
var RK = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId;
var CommentSchema = Schema({
    body: {type: String},
    chapterId: {type: RK, ref: 'Chapter'},
    by: {type: RK, ref: 'User'},
    children: [{
        type: RK,
        ref: 'Comment'

     }]
}, {timestamps: true});
```

Comment: tbh tho it seems like there's quite a few questions regarding something like this and no good answers. guess ill try my best to come up with a decent one.

Answer (score 1):

```
let dependencySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    dependencyComment: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: false
    },
    dependencyAuthor: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: false
    }
});

let CommentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    //Rest of you schema
    children: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: [dependencySchema]

     }]
}, {timestamps: true});
```

this way you nest the comment to N-th Level